# How do I create a menu item when a node is submitted?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks, nodes

I have created a new content type and want to add a menu item every time a user creates a new node for this content type.  I can catch the submission using [hook_node_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7), but I don't know how to add it to a menu from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [menu_link_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) function.

```
<?php
$item = array(
  'link_path' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
  'link_title' => $node->title,
);
menu_link_save($item);
?>
```

Comment: And "After calling this function, rebuild the menu cache using menu_cache_clear_all()."